# I am trying hard to achieve expected output, but failing to create a reusable code for below problem statement. Any suggestions?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Define a class dynamically. Class name should be taken from user by standard input(command line)
Then prompt user for a method name and a single line of code. This method should be defined as instance method in the class above dynamically with the code entered by user.
Tell user that the class and method is defined.
Then call this instance method and display the result

What I am trying to do is - 
"Making a class with initialize method which takes the dynamic class name method and then creating class there, after that creating an instance of that class there only in initialize method.Then assigning it to a class instance variable and calling the greet method/ dynamic method on that instance."
But failing in this process.
I want to do this with OOPS and main problem is accepting user input and assigning it to dynamic method and class.

```
class MethodCreator
  @my_class_instance_var = ""

  class << self
    attr_accessor :my_class_instance_var
   end

  def initialize(class_name)
    cl = Class.new
    @my_class_instance_var = Object.const_set(class_name, cl)
  end
  def create_method(method_name, code_str)
    self.class.define_method(method_name, code_str)
  end
end

puts "Please enter the class name:"
class_name = gets.chomp
puts "Please enter the method name you wish to define:"
method_name = gets.chomp
puts "Please enter the method's code:"
code_str = gets.chomp

obj = MethodCreator.new(class_name)

obj.my_class_instance_var.method_name
```

Expected :

```
Please enter the class name: User
Please enter the method name you wish to define: greet
Please enter the method's code: "Welcome from #{self.class} class. I am #{self}"

--- Result ---
Hello, Your class User with method greet is ready. Calling: User.new.greet:
"Welcome from User class. I am <User#123456>"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found one solution to this problem. I will be glad if this can help someone, who is struggling with meta-programming like me.

```
class MethodCreator
  def initialize(class_name)
    @klass = Class.new
    Object.const_set(class_name, @klass)
  end
  def new_method(method_name, code_str)
    @klass.instance_eval do
        define_method(method_name) { instance_eval(code_str)}
    end
  end
  def call(method_name)
    @klass.new.send(method_name)
  end
end

puts "Please enter the class name:"
class_name = gets.chomp
puts "Please enter the method name you wish to define:"
method_name = gets.chomp
puts "Please enter the method's code:"
code_str = gets.chomp

obj = MethodCreator.new(class_name)

obj.new_method(method_name, code_str)
puts obj.call(method_name)
```